# read and write from file to file until EOF in c under linux

Tags: c, linux

i have this code in c to open file and write its contents to another file ,but when i run it wrong results and some lines only copied and goes in infinite loop :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>


//static int    read_cnt;
//static char   *read_ptr;
//static char   read_buf[1024];


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //i have a variable size which is an int and is the byte size of the file
    //i got the byte size of file from stat
    int fileread = open("/tmp/des.py",'r');
    char buffer[1024];



    while((fileread = read(fileread, buffer, sizeof(buffer))>0));
    {
        if(fileread < 0) 
              printf("error write");
    }


    int filewrite = open("/tmp/original.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT);

    while ((filewrite = write(filewrite, buffer, sizeof(buffer))>0))
    {
        if(filewrite < 0)
              printf("error write");
    }


    close(filewrite);
    close(fileread);

    return 0;
}
```

so how to solve this problem

Comment: Note that you can clean your headers by calling .h only once (i.e. stdio).

Answer (score 2):

OP attempted to copy the entire contents but has 2 disjoint while loops.  The first reads all the data into the same small buffer.  Then the last contents of the buffer are used to write that buffer endlessly.

**Only 1 while loop needed**.  Write buffer needs to use length of data read, not `sizeof buffer`.

```
int fileread = open("/tmp/des.py", O_RDONLY);
int filewrite = open("/tmp/original.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT);
// After successfully opening ...
char buffer[1024];
ssize_t inlen;
ssize_t outlen;
while((inlen = read(fileread, buffer, sizeof buffer)) > 0) {
  outlen = write(filewrite, buffer, inlen);  // Note use of inlen
  if (inlen != outlen) {
    handle_error();
  }
}
if (inlen < 0) {
  handle_error();
}
close(filewrite);
close(fileread);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
    while(   (fileread=read(fileread,buffer,sizeof(buffer))>0));
```

you overwrite the value of `fileread`, which was a file handle, with the number of bytes read.  The code should be

```
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while(   (bytesRead=read(fileread,buffer,sizeof(buffer))>0));
```

Same for the write section

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
size_t bytesRead = 0;
while((bytesRead=read(fileread,buffer,sizeof(buffer))>0));
```

You need this because `read` returns how many symbols were read so in your case you just overwrited file handle.